# How to reset the USB Hub in Windows 10 Commandline

Tags: windows-10, command-line, usb

In Windows 10 device manager, for the "Generic USB Hub" & "USB Root Hub" there is a new function under advanced tab called: "Reset Hub".

I want to be able to reset these with each wakeup/restart.
Can you tell me how i can call this function via commandline?

[Here you can see the new menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXPCB.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset USB device every boot (Windows)](http://superuser.com/questions/681301/how-to-reset-usb-device-every-boot-windows)

Comment: Not really a duplicate as that question wants to reset a specific device and this one wants to reset the Generic Hub.

Comment: The Generic Hub is also a device and DevCon does look like a solution.

Comment: like others said you could use "devcon restart *" and use a batch file and attach that batch file in your startup folder or in your "run" key in regedit

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: For me this is a duplicate. If you would like, go ahead and answer it.

Comment: @harrymc Perhaps this should instead be a separate question, but some evidence that the newly-introduced "reset hub" performs the same action as a devcon-initiated "restart" would be useful. Even if the answer ends up being the same, the question asked is different.

Comment: (same to @PimpJuiceIT, et. al.)

Comment: @AlmostSerious could you share with us the output of this powershell command? (execute in powershell) `$computer = "LocalHost"; $namespace = "root\CIMV2"; Get-WmiObject -class Win32_USBHub -computername $computer -namespace $namespace`

Comment: @Bob: I think this would only qualify as a comment on the answer in the duplicate post.

Comment: @harrymc It *might* have, if the suggested question were actually a duplicate. Not only was it asked before the "reset hub" button existed (AFAICT), but the answer there suggests *removing and rescanning* the device, which is even further removed from this question (not even `restart`, which itself may or may not be the same as `reset hub`).

Comment: Just one example of how remove + rescan is different: it could potentially auto-detect and install a different driver from the previous entry. That would be a Bad Thing™.

Comment: @Bob: Based on that answer it's easy enough to create here an answer that doesn't do rescan. You seem to be able to do this by yourself, so why start this bounty?

Comment: @harrymc (1) Because I found it interesting enough, (2) because I *can't* seem to confirm that devcon (restart or otherwise) actually does the same thing as this "reset hub" button, (3) the rescanning behaviour is just *one* obvious example of why that question's answer is not necessarily applicable; **the question itself is different**, (4) perhaps someone has a better answer.

Comment: For (2) there is no documentation. You could test and see if the effects seem similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the
[DevCon sources on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/setup/devcon).

On examination of the program, there are no surprises.
DevCon uses the
[WDK for Windows 10, version 1709](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware)
(Windows Development Kit) of which it is a part.
The WDK is the only tool on Windows to develop, test, and deploy Windows drivers.

Specifically, DevCon uses a unified function, `ControlCallback`,
for doing the operations of Enable, Disable and Restart.
Restart is therefore equivalent to doing Disable and Enable.

There is no other tool than the WDK to operate on devices,
and there are no other functions in the WDK to enable/disable devices
than the ones that are used by DevCon.

As the Device Manager is also written using the WDK,
I would say that it almost surely does the same operations
for "Reset Hub" as DevCon does for Restart.
There are no other operations in the WDK for doing this,
as far as I have been able to find.

It should be noted that the operation itself is executed by the driver
of the device, to which the WDK passes the command.
The actual action that is done depends on the driver of the device.
Examining in Device Manager the drivers for the
"Generic USB Hub" and "USB Root Hub" devices
shows that the same drivers are used for both, so
the command "Reset Hub" or Restart very likely does a very similar
operation for both devices.

(This answer cannot be definitive, since the source of the Device Manager
is not published by Microsoft, but I believe it is correct.)